# Criação de interface gráfica em R

Tags: r

Gostaria de saber se há algum pacote que permita criar uma interface gráfica para o usuário com botões, caixa de texto e tudo mais. E como gerar um .exe a partir do código em R?

Comment: O R tem uma interface com o Qt disponível aqui: https://github.com/ggobi/qtbase .
Eu nunca usei e não conheço bons projetos que fazem interfaces deste tipo com o R.
Ele simplesmente não é bom para fazer esse tipo de programas.

O R está mais próximo da web, com [shiny](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny) e [plumber](https://github.com/trestletech/plumber), por exemplo.

Não é possível criar executáveis a partir de scripts do R.

Comment: Mesmo após 2 anos me vejo a vistas com esse problema novamente. Conheci o RInno (https://github.com/ficonsulting/RInno) que cria um instalador para rodar apps do shiny em standalone na máquina do usuário.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez o  "[R commander (`Rcmdr`)](http://www.rcommander.com/)" seja o que você está procurando. Vide [site](https://socialsciences.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Misc/Rcmdr/) e agora tem até um [livro](https://socialsciences.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/RCommander/). É uma interface gráfica para o R que possui vários plugins. Aqui, inclusive, vários botões, menus e caixas de seleção estão traduzidos para português. Também é possível encontrar algumas apostilas em português, ex: pdfs [aqui](https://edisciplinas.usp.br/pluginfile.php/1855815/mod_resource/content/1/Rcmdr%20-%20Apostila%20de%20estat%C3%ADstica%20b%C3%A1sica.pdf) e [aqui](http://www.inf.ufsc.br/~vera.carmo/Ensino_2013_2/Software%20R.pdf). Para instalar, digite `install.packages("Rcmdr")` no console  depois, para usar: `library(Rcmdr)`. O R Commander pode ser usado junto com o RStudio.

Outra opção, com interface mais bonitinha e outras funcionalidades, é usar o R através do RStudio e instalar alguns "[RStudio addins](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2016/02/you-can-now-extend-rstudio-with-add-ins.html)". Sugiro instalar primeiramente o [`addinslist`](https://deanattali.com/blog/addinslist-package/) que vai permitir que você encontre [outros addins](https://community.rstudio.com/t/what-are-your-favorite-rstudio-addins/1771).

Quanto à criação de um executável a partir de um código, não sei responder.

Comment: 2 anos depois ainda me vejo proximo a este problema novamente. Depois de algumas pesquisas achei o gWdigets (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gWidgets/vignettes/gWidgets.pdf) ele integra o R com GTK. Ainda estou nos estudos iniciais, mas ele está bem próximo do que preciso.

Comment: Com relação ao executável estou trabalhnado numa integração do shiny com o RInno (https://github.com/ficonsulting/RInno) que cria um instalador para rodar apps do shiny em standalone na máquina do usuário.