# Interface gráfica para R

Tags: r

Olá! Preciso criar uma interface gráfica capaz de rodar scripts R já prontos e busco sugestões de quais ferramentas posso usar. Os scripts são complexos e servem basicamente para fazer processamento de imagens via satélites. A interface seria bem simples, com um botão para cada script. Até agora só tentei trabalhar com Java, por meio de uma integração entre as duas linguagens, usando o RServe, que é um TCP/IP, porém não obtive resultados tão bons quanto o esperado.

Comment: Veja se a resposta e o comentário dessa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/250771/cria%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-interface-gr%C3%A1fica-em-r) esclarece sua dúvida.

Comment: Isso me parece simples implementar com shiny.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Criação de interface gráfica em R](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/250771/cria%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-interface-gr%c3%a1fica-em-r)